# Help with a melody from a chord progression on piano

Tags: piano, chords

Right now I have a chord progression I like (D min, 1st inversion A min, C maj, 1st inversion A min) and want some good tips for making a melody.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by outlining the harmony with arbitrary chord tones(notes that belong to the chord you are playing at the time). You can pick the rhythmic ideas, as long as they sound good to you. Having some rhythmic variety is always a plus, though.

Now play what you have. Sounds all right, but it doesn't sound great, a bit basic, right? Now we can add some non chord tones. These are notes that are outside of the given chord. There are several types of non-chord tones. To name a few, passing notes(notes that exist in between 2 notes a third apart, making the third move by step), appoggiaturas(notes that are sounded by a leap and resolved by step to a chord tone) and suspensions(a held tone from the previous chord that resolves by step to a chord tone) are all examples of non-chord tones. Where we add non chord tones is pretty much arbitrary, but a non-chord tone that exists on a beat, especially if it's on a downbeat, is often associated with much greater tension than unaccented ones. These are called accented non-chord tones, and are great for expressiveness, especially if they happen to be chromatic.

We can also consider phrasing. If you plan on endlessly repeating your chord progression(assuming that every chord lasts a bar), it's not that much of a problem, because every phrase compacts into 4 bars(symmetrical phrasing, especially phrases of 2, 4, or 8 bars, often feel more stable than irregular phrasing, or that of 3, 5, 7, etc. bars). But, in future writing, you may want to experiment with some different phrasing, which often adds interest and/or shock.

These are the basics of melody writing. Furthermore, these are guidelines, not rules. They are often broken, sometimes making harshly dissonant, crunching effects that work really well in context. But the things that I said are mainly to help make a harmonically pleasant, but colorful line. On a side note, I'd change the last chord to Amaj7.